# iam getting data from firebase cloudstore. i want to pass data in to static const String = "here';

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

iam getting data from firebase cloud_store. i want to pass data in to static const String = "here';

```
 Firestore.instance.collection('postman').document('FdsgttSX1Fc8').get()
  .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  var link = ds['link_data'];
  assert(link is String);
  print("link value: $link");
  return link ;
  });

try {
        final response = await http.get(url);
  if (200 == response.statusCode) {
    return parseMovies(response.body);
  } else {
    return Movies();
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error ${e.toString()}');
  return Movies();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3KNd.jpg)

Comment: How about first saving it into variable and then declare a const and assign this variable value to it?

Comment: i dont know how to write that code.could please write it down?